# Angular ternary operators

Tags: angularjs, ternary-operator

I'm attempting to use a ternary operator to set up a portion of my template:

`account.accountType === "" ? "" : "Type: " + account.accountType`

This code snippet should leave out the Type label if it is null. However, the type label is always present:

Evaluates to true: `Type:` 
Evaluates to false: `Type: {{ account.accountType }}`

My desired behavior would be:

Evaluates to true: `""` 
Evaluates to false: `Type: {{ account.accountType }}`

Is this a shortcoming of angular ternary operators, or an error in my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`""` is not the same as `null`.

I suggest you make use of `null`, `""`, etc.'s behavior as "falsy" and do the following:

```
account.accountType ? "Type: " + account.accountType : ""
```

or even (thanks to gustavohenke):

```
account.accountType && "Type: " + account.accountType
```

If you want to conditionally include HTML in your view, you're probably best off using something like `ng-if`:

```
<span ng-if="account.accountType" class=".....">Type: {{ account.accountType }}</span>
```

Comment: Could go even shorter: `account.accountType && "Type: " + account.accountType`

Comment: Is there any way to include HTML tags in the "Type: " condition?

Comment: @mattchue Not that I know of. If you want to manipulate the HTML in your view, there are better ways to do it than to try to use the conditional operator (see my edit).